# Powershell get day of the week in yyMMdd format

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the date from a file name "BW-121113-CF1.pdf". So I have my date 121113, how do I figure out what day of the week that was. I tried:    "{0:yyMMdd}" -f (get-date) "121113". But of course that didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
get-date "11/13/12" -format dddd
```

That get's me the right day of the week. But I need the get-date to understand that "121113" is the say date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
([datetime]::ParseExact("121113", "yyMMdd", 
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture )).DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got many solutions :

`([datetime]"11/13/12").DayOfWeek")` will give you the day of the week in .NET natural language (english)

try : `[datetime]::parse("13/11/2012")`

or : `("{0:dddd}" -f [datetime]::parse("13/11/2012"))`

or : `([datetime]"11/13/2012").tostring("dddd")`

in your special case :

convertion : `$aDate = ("121113" -replace '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})','$2/$3/$1')`
gives : `11/13/12` in `$aDate`
And : `([datetime]$aDate).dayofweek`

So :

```
([datetime]("121113" -replace '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})','$2/$3/$1')).dayofweek
```